# Using ResultSetMetaData with same column name in 2 tables

Tags: java, sql, database, sybase, resultset

I want to get column names from 2 tables and then their value using `ResultSetMetaData` and `ResultSet`. Let's say table myTable has columns x, y and z. I do

```
 Select * from table myTable A,myTable B where A.x = B.y
```

and I want to use B.z 's value in my code.

`ResultSetMetaData` will list columns as x y z x y z , so how do I differentiate z's value from aliases A and B?

I need to use * in the query since it improves my performance. So I can't mention column names there. Is there any way I can get the value of column B.z using column names of `ResultSet`? I mean is there any way that `ResultSetMetaData` will list columns as A.x, A.y, A.z, B.x, B.y, and B.z ?

Comment: I think your assumption that `SELECT *` gives you better performance than `SELECT col,col,col` is wrong.

Comment: its not assumption ...its my actual use case with large table and large data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to specify the columnnames (with aliases), then you will need to retrieve the values by index, not by column label. The [`ResultSet` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) explicitly says:

> When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns have the **same name**, the value of the **first matching column** will be returned. The column name option is designed to be used when column names are used in the SQL query that generated the result set. **For columns that are NOT explicitly named in the query, it is best to use column numbers.** If column names are used, the programmer should take care to guarantee that they uniquely refer to the intended columns, which can be assured with the SQL AS clause.

(emphasis mine)

If you want to differentiate between columns then you can use [`ResultSetMetaData.getTableName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName-int-), but it won't help you with retrieval (except to find the "right" index to use). Note that not all databases support providing the table name.

Comment: That is what i am currently doing the index way.. i thought if there is something  out of the box ..it would be good ..Thanks a lot anyways...

Comment: @user1107108 Unfortunately there is no way to do that: the API explicitly says there isn't as shown above.

Comment: How can we do this if we are using spring jdbctemplate.

Comment: @neerajbharti Exactly the same: specify aliases for columns in your query, or retrieve by index instead of name. Or use the methods accepting a RowMapper so you can access the result set metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more duplicate of [JDBC ResultSet get columns with table alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias).

Use rs.getMetaData().getTableName(colid) which provides the table name of each column and you have to generate your own hashmap with key as tablename and value as list of columnnames.