# HSQLDB: column not found

Tags: java, sql, left-join, hsqldb, functional-testing

I am writing some functional tests for my application using HSQLDB. My app generates the following SQL request:

```
SELECT 
CLIENT.account_id, 
CLIENT.client_code, 
SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id, 
SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.address_code
FROM CLIENT 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9 
    ON SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.address_code = CLIENT.shipping_address_code AND (SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id = 4) 
WHERE CLIENT.account_id = 4
```

This request is valid and works with my code (JDBC + MySQL). When I try to execute my functional tests with HSQLDB, I got the following exception:

```
resultSet.findColumn("CLIENT.account_id"); //Works
resultSet.findColumn("SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id"); //Exception

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.findColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.inventis.bw.data.DataBaseUtil.loadBean(DataBaseUtil.java:419)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Column not found: SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
It looks like the problem is coming from the table alias.

```
logger.debug("address account id => " + resultSet.findColumn("ADDRESS.account_id")); // Works
logger.debug("address account id => " + resultSet.findColumn("SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id")); //Exception
```

Accessing the column value with the table name works perfectly but if I use the table alias name, the exception is thrown. Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should accept @Gordon's answer. When selecting from an `SQL` result set, one should not rely on table (alias) prefixes. Just reference the (aliased) column names **without** prefix. Make unique column aliases and you'll have done the right thing.

Comment: `When selecting from an SQL result set, one should not rely on table (alias) prefixes.` Why's that? my code works perfectly based on the aliases, only HSQLDB is failing.

Comment: For instance, from [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn%28java.lang.String%29): "the label for the column **specified with the SQL AS clause**. If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is the **name of the column**." See also Q&A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias).

Comment: A shot in the dark: Try using the word AS explicitly by changing "LEFT JOIN ADDRESS SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9 " to "LEFT JOIN ADDRESS AS SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9 ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine your problem is that two columns have the same alias "account_id" and this causes confusion.  Try giving them different names:

```
SELECT CLIENT.account_id as client_account_id,
       CLIENT.client_code, 
       SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.account_id as shipping_account_id
       SHIPPINGADDRESS10A9.address_code
```

Just curious, can you write the query like this?

```
SELECT c.account_id as client_account_id,
       c.client_code, 
       a.account_id as shipping_account_id
       a.address_code
FROM CLIENT c LEFT JOIN
     ADDRESS a 
     ON a.address_code = c.shipping_address_code AND 
        a.account_id = c.account_id
WHERE c.account_id = 4;
```

This should be equivalent and makes it clear that you do not need to return the `account_id` twice in the `select`.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff, thanks for your answer. I updated my question. It looks like the problem is coming from the table alias not from the column itself.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because using the alias on the column worked but your explication is not really accurate. HSQLB does not handled alias like MySQL does.

Comment: @dbaq Yes, HSQLDB does not accept a table alias in combination with the column name. It does accept the actual table name when used with the column name. So if you simply use `address.account_id` and completely avoid the long table alias, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I like Gordon Linoff's answer. I just wanted to add that you need to specify __ in the connection string ";get_column_name=false" if you want it to work in HSQLDB

Answer (score -1):

you should to try this SQL request to declare the join correctly:

```
SELECT 
C.account_id, 
C.client_code, 
S.account_id, 
S.address_code
FROM CLIENT C,ADDRESS S
WHERE S.address_code = C.shipping_address_code AND C.account_id = 4
```

and you will to try this

```
resultSet.findColumn("C.account_id"); 
resultSet.findColumn("S.account_id");
```

Comment: No I need to do a LEFT JOIN.