# hsql Java table column access problems

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb

In other database languages you can structure your queries to define an instance of a table, such as:

```
SELECT a.foo, a.bar FROM ACME a WHERE a.ID=1;
```

And perform something like

```
rs.getInt("a.foo");
```

to obtain the value of the first row of this table. I am having trouble doing this seemingly basic feature in hsql and was wondering if there was an easy solution or if others have experienced this. If I execute the above query and attempt to access 'a.foo' I get the following error using hsql:

```
org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcResultSet.findColumn(Unknown Source)
org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
```

However, if I change the access to

```
rs.getInt("foo");
```

everything works fine. What gives? Why does hsql have difficulties retrieving 'a.foo' when the query is defined that way? These series of commands work fine in MySQL.

Comment: You may find this similar question and responses on stackoverflow very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the solution provided there is similar to what @davidxxx provided below... revising all the queries. This syntax seems like a standard format that all rdbms should support.

Comment: Of course, dbms supports the syntax. The problem here is not the dbms but the library you use to communicate with your dmbs (JDBC driver). It is the same thing when you write a JPQL query, you have some rules and limitations if you want that it works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how other dbms behavior with this syntax but the hsqldb behavior seems to match with the specification of

```
 int java.sql.ResultSet.getInt(String columnLabel) throws SQLException
```

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as an int in the Java programming language.

**Parameters**:

> columnLabel the label for the column specified with the SQL AS clause.
>   If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is the name of
>   the column Returns:

In your query, `**a.fo**`represents the `fo` column. It is not an alias. If you want to use a alias, you could try that :

```
SELECT a.foo as 'myFoo', a.bar FROM ACME a WHERE a.ID=1;
```

And get the value like that :

```
rs.getInt("myFoo");
```

Comment: Thanks. While your solution certainly does work, this means I would have to go back through all the code and change all the queries to support this... which I might have to do regardless.

Comment: If changing the queries has a some cost, you could try with H2 database, if you are lucky, maybe you could have another behavior. But anyway, if you use after another dbms, you risk to have still the problem. You have indeed no choice but re-write your queries. Re-writing a part of the jdbc driver would be of course a very bad idea.