# Use getColumnName() or getColumnLabel() for getString()?

Tags: java, jdbc, sas

I am facing an issue with the SAS jdbc driver I have not seen before, and wondered what would be the correct JDBC behaviour.

Suppose I have some `ResultSetMetaData`:

```
metadata.getColumnName(index) -> col1
metadata.getColumnLabel(index) -> Column1
```

This would be the SQL result when running this query:

```
SELECT col1 AS Column1
```

When getting a value from a `ResultSet`, I expect to use this:

```
rs.getString("Column1")
```

But instead, I seem to have to use:

```
rs.getString("col1")
```

Is this to be expected and where my assumptions wrong? Or is this driver-specific behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JDBC, you retrieve values of a result set by column label (the alias), not by column name. In the code in your question, the proper way to retrieve a value is using `rs.getString("Column1")` (or - as it is handled case-insensitive - `rs.getString("COLUMN1")`)

This is documented in the API, as all `String` based getters have the following documentation:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `columnLabel` - the label for the column specified with the SQL `AS`
>   clause. If the SQL `AS` clause was not specified, then the label is
>   the name of the column

Historically, JDBC 3 and earlier did not clearly discern between column labels and column names, which - to this day - results in drivers that require you to get by column name, or allow you to get both by column name or label, or return the column name from [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-) or the column label from [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName-int-), or have configuration options to set which behavior to use.

Comment: Thanks! So the SAS driver I'm using is behaving wrongly.

Comment: @RobAu if the SAS driver requires you to use `rs.getString("col1")`, then yes, it is a bug in its implementation as that is not the behaviour specified in the JDBC specification and API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using alias it seems the jdbc is expecting alias in that column name argument.

I found an related link for this : [DB alias Resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias).
 Hope this might be helpful

Comment: Thanks, is seems the SAS driver is a bit oddly behaving then?