# DAO Controller for a foreign key in java jstl

Tags: java, jdbc

I have 2 tables to join. The first table is named `students` with several fields => (studentID,name, firstname, sex, dateofbirth, address, phone, email, status, dateregister, licenseID)

My second table is named `licenses` with 2 fields => (licenseID, type_license).

My SQL request seems to be correct, here is below:

```
SELECT students.studentID, students.name, students.firstname, students.dateofbirth, students.sex, students.address, 
students.phone, students.email, students.status, students.dateofbirth, licenses.type_license 

FROM students 

INNER JOIN licenses 

ON students.licenseID = licenses.licenseID
```

I think my models are ok also

**Model Student**

```
package com.autoecole.model;


public class Student {

    private int studentID;
    private String name;
    private String firstname;
    private String dateofbirth;
    private String sex;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String status;
    private String dateregister;
    private int licenseID;

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setDateofbirth(String dateofbirth) {
        this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setDateregister(String dateregister) {
        this.dateregister = dateregister;
    }

    public void setLicenseID(int licenseID) {
        this.licenseID = licenseID;
    }
    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getDateofbirth() {
        return dateofbirth;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getDateregister() {
        return dateregister;
    }

    public int getLicenseID() {
        return licenseID;
    }   

}
```

**Model License**

```
public class License {

    private int licenseID;
    private String type_license;

    public void setLicenseID(int licenseID) {
        this.licenseID = licenseID;
    }

    public void setTypeLicense(String type_license) {
        this.type_license = type_license;
    }

    public int getLicenseID() {
        return licenseID;
    }

    public String getTypeLicense() {
        return type_license;
    }

}
```

In my getAllRecordsStudents() method I have an error message on this line:

```
 studentBean.setTypeLicense(rs.getString("licenses.type_license"));
```

"***The method setTypeLicense(String) is undefined for the type Student***"

```
public static List getAllRecordsStudents(){  
        List <Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();  

        try{  
            Connection con=getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT students.studentID, students.name, students.firstname, students.dateofbirth, students.sex, students.address, students.phone, students.email, students.status, students.dateofbirth, licenses.type_license FROM students INNER JOIN licenses ON students.licenseID = licenses.licenseID");  
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
            while(rs.next()){  
                Student studentBean =new Student();  
                studentBean.setStudentID(rs.getInt("studentID"));  
                studentBean.setName(rs.getString("name"));  
                studentBean.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname")); 
                studentBean.setDateofbirth(rs.getString("dateofbirth"));  
                studentBean.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));  
                studentBean.setAddress(rs.getString("address")); 
                studentBean.setPhone(rs.getString("phone")); 
                studentBean.setEmail(rs.getString("email")); 
                studentBean.setStatus(rs.getString("status")); 
                studentBean.setDateregister(rs.getString("dateregister")); 
                studentBean.setTypeLicense(rs.getString("licenses.type_license"));
                list.add(studentBean);  
            }  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        return list;  
    }
```

**Edit:** Here is screenshot

[image]

**AddStudent method()**

```
public static int addStudent(Student studentBean){  
        int status=0;  
        try{  
            Connection con=getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into students(name, firstname, sex, dateofbirth, address, phone, email, status, dateregister, licenseID) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");  
            ps.setString(1,studentBean.getName());   
            ps.setString(2,studentBean.getFirstname());   
            ps.setString(3,studentBean.getDateofbirth());    
            ps.setString(4,studentBean.getSex());  
            ps.setString(5,studentBean.getAddress());
            ps.setString(6, studentBean.getPhone());
            ps.setString(7, studentBean.getEmail());
            ps.setString(8, studentBean.getStatus());
            ps.setString(9, studentBean.getDateregister());
            ps.setInt(10, studentBean.getLicenseID());
            status=ps.executeUpdate();  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        return status;  
    }
```

Sincerely, I don't understand what I should do?

Comment: are you using an IDE? does it have syntax highlighting? if not I recommend it, as this could probably be caught by the IDE you're using

Comment: @juju: Eclipse, I edited my first message with a screenshot.^^

Comment: you can't set an int as a String, see my edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC ResultSet get columns with table alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias)

Comment: my problem is perhaps my addstudent() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a join you won't need to define the table name in your result set lookup, as it returns a new view of both tables.

```
rs.getString("licenses.type_license");
```

change this to

```
rs.getString("type_license");
```

and it should work.

If you can, have a look at the full table in the database that's returned when you run that query

**EDIT 
They're the wrong types. `type_license` is a String in licence, and int in student.

to get the value you'll need to parse it or change one of the types. I like;

```
studentBean.setTypeLicense(Integer.valueOf(rs.getString("type_license")));
```

but there a few different ways you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still get the same error.

Comment: does the query actually return results, and if so, what's the header of the column?

Comment: oh haha, missed the type difference in the models.

Comment: I tried your modification and I always have the same problem. I don't understand :-(

Comment: is it the same error? can you update the question with an error if so?

Comment: i don't believe, can you show the error after you've set it to a differrent type pls?

Comment: It is unnecessary to use `Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(...))`, using `rs.getInt(..)` should work as well in a JDBC-compliant database.

Comment: depends on what they want to do with the field I guess, if that class is used for anything else - parsing might be a good compromise.